# Displaying content in table format

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to create a html table and display the content in a tabular format

Description :- I have a content with comma(,) seperated values ex:a,b,c,d,e,f
I have rows number ex:4
I have columns number ex:5

These three information is stored in DB while fetching data its should create a table with number of rows and columns specified in DB , And the content should load in table like each value(comma seperated) should be in one cell

Code I have tried so far:

```
$resultSet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet);
$tableContent = $result[0];
$tableResult = explode(',',$tableContent);
foreach($tableResult as $tabRes) {
echo $tabRes."<br/>";
}
$rows = $result[1];
$cols = $result[2];
$table = "<table border=\"1\">";
for($i=1; $i<=$rows; $i++){
    $table .= "<tr>";
    for($j=1; $j<=$cols; $j++){
        foreach($tableResult as $tabRes) {
        $table .= "<td>$tabRes</td>";
        }
    }
    $table .= "</tr>";
}
$table .= "</table>";
echo $table;
```

Comment: And what is the question? What is not working as expected?

Comment: Table is not generating as expected

Comment: What is expected and what does it do instead?!

Comment: the contents should be in tablular formet like
a b c
e f g

But its giving like
a b c d e f
a b c d e f

Comment: But I think my answer is still wrong, cause you're question is very confusing... What is your table in the DB look like? For me it's:
`| a,b,c,d,e,f | 3 | 6 |` and only one time.

Answer (score 2):

Move you closing `tr` into the first loop block.

Write

```
    $table .= "</tr>";
  }
```

instead of

```
  }
    $table .= "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edited answer:**

```
$resultSet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet); 
$content = $result[0];
$rows = $result[1];
$columns =  $result[2];

$cellcontent = explode(',', $content);
$table = '<table border="1">'; 
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    $table .= '<tr>'; 
    for($j = 0; $j < $columns; $j++) { 
        $table .= '<td>'.$cellcontent[$j].'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>'; 
}
$table .= '</table>'; 
echo $table;
```

**EDIT:**

For better understanding I try to do the DB look inside here (this is what I understand from reading your question):

```
|  Content    | rows | columns |
| a,b,c,d,e,f |   3  |    6    |
```

Is that right? Or are there more entries? Like this:

```
|  Content    | rows | columns |
| a,b,c,d,e,f |   3  |    6    |
| g,h,i,j,k,l |   1  |    6    |
| m,n,o,p,q,r |   5  |    6    |
```

Or is the content much longer and need to be parted into rows and columns (first content cell has 2 x 6 contents, so first line will be in first row and second in second row)?

```
|  Content    | rows | columns |
| a,b,c,d,e,f |   2  |    6    |
| g,h,i,j,k,l |      |         |
| ------------|------|---------|
| g,h,i,j,k,l |   1  |    6    |
| m,n,o,p,q,r |   5  |    6    |
```

Cause right now, I just repeat the same row everytime.

Comment: Let's say you have content to fill 6 cells of table and what is your rows and columns for this?